# Get words from string array in c using whitespace character

Tags: c, arrays

I have tried make a program which is fills up a string array with string that is given by the user and after that i run into a problem with the idea that how coud i examine that how many words are in the array. I examined the whitespace characterts but it does not work well, i guess .Because whatever the array contains ,it writes flase value : e.g its contain 2 words when there is only 1 word in it.

```
int db =0;
char array[255];

void string(char str[]){
    printf("Enter a string:");
    scanf("%s",str);
}

void words(char str[]){
    int i=0;
    int len = strlen(str);

    while( str[i]!=len)
    {
        if(str[i]==' ')
            db++;
        i++;
    }
}


int main(int argc,char** argv){
    string(array);
    words(array);
    printf("its contain %d words",db);
}
```

Comment: read with words with `fgets`, might be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems, but the main is using `scanf` instead of `gets`. If you'll run this function you'll see that `scanf` fails to read beyond whitespace, where `gets` doesn't: *(my input was `"123 456 789"`)*

```
void string(char str[]){
    printf("Enter a string:");
    scanf("%s",str);
    printf("%s\n", str); // the string was scanned until 1st whitespace
    gets(str);
    printf("%s\n", str); // proper string was read
}
```

---

The 2nd thing to note is warnings. The return type of `strlen()` isn't `int`, it's `size_t` ([man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen)). Also, you are comparing not matching types (char != int):

```
void words(char str[]){
    int i=0;               // change to size_t because it is checked against len
    int len = strlen(str); // change to size_t

    while( str[i]!=len) // should be i != len because you check the location in the string against the length, not against the char itself!!
    {
        if(str[i]==' ')
            db++;
        i++;
    }
}
```

---

The 3rd thing is logic. What if your string has indeed 2 words: "hello world"? you would only count white_spaces and assume you have only one word. I would add something like:

void words(char str[]){
    size_t i=0;
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);

```
while(i!=len)
{
    if(str[i]==' ')
        db++;
    i++;
}
if(i) // if i is positive, there must have been a white_space -> add the 1st word because it wasn't counted (Assuming the string must start with a word and not a white_space!!)
    i++;
```

}

---

This is how I would rewrite it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int db =0;
char array[255];

void string(char str[]){
    printf("Enter a string:");
    gets(str);
}

void words(char str[]){
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t len = strlen(str);

    while(i != len)
    {
        if(str[i]==' ')
            db++;
        i++;
    }

    if(i)
        i++;
}


int main(/*no need for argc, argv. You can leave them there, but I prefer to omit if not used*/){
    string(array);
    words(array);
    printf("its contain %d words",db);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that there are still some issues:

- What happens if more than one white space is entered between 2 words?
- What happens if a white space is the first char (I assumed not, but can it be?)
- What happens if the input string is too long?

Answer (score 0):

Analyse main() function

```
int main(int argc,char** argv){
    string(array);
    words(array);
    printf("its contain %d words",db);
   }
```

when you are calling `words(array) function` what is `array` ? nothing. if you are taking `array` as a global then what's the the needs of passing to function & catching with `str` .

Next,

```
void string(char str[]){
        printf("Enter a string:");
        scanf("%s",str);
}
```

modify above function as below if you want to scan strings with white spaces.

```
void string(char str[]){
        int len;//define it 
        fgets(str,len,stdin);//TO READ STRINGS WITH WHITESPACES
}
```

Next come to your logic, what you want to achieve with `while( str[i]!=len)` ?
Rotate loop upto NULL & and then modify the condition for finding no of words as below.

```
void words(char str[]){
        int i=0;
        //   int len = strlen(str);
        while( str[i]! = NULL)
        {
                if(str[i]==' ' && str[i+1] !=' ')
                        db++;
                i++;
        }

}
```

complete program as

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void words(char str[]);
int db =0;
char array[255];
void string(char str[]){
        int n;// define it 
        printf("Enter a string:");
        fgets(str,n,stdin);// now data is there in str not in array variable thats why call words() function from here only it's a better option
        words(str);// call from here bcz now you have str
}
void words(char str[]){
        int i=0;

        printf("string = %s \n",str);
        while( str[i] != '\0')
        {
                if( (str[i]==' ' && str[i+1] !=' ') || str[i+1] == '\0')
                        db++;
                i++;
        }
        printf("db = %d \n",db);
}


int main(int argc,char** argv){
    string(array);
    printf("its contain %d words",db);
   }
```

I hope it will helps.

Answer (score -2):

I thought it's the easiest one. You have to start with your counter

```
int db = 1;
```